# controlling blank lines in Google Play app description

Tags: android, google-play

When publishing the description of my app in Google Play, I'm having a hard time controlling whether blank lines appear between my paragraphs of text.  The text I submit always contains blank lines between paragraphs, but some of them get dropped in the published version.  I find that if I use a <br> tag, I get two blank lines, which is not what I want, either.

Anybody figured this out?

Comment: If you are copying and pasting the description from somewhere else it might be that some of the blank lines are using windows line endings and some are using unix line endings. You could try pasting the description into a text editor that allows you to see which line endings are being used.

Comment: Thanks, that was a good guess and seemed plausible, as I was doing some copying/pasting, but after investigating, it doesn't seem to be the cause of my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to stumble upon a solution through trial and error.  What works for me is to separate paragraphs with a newline, a space, and another newline.  In other words, a blank line between paragraphs that includes a space on that blank line.